# Code works when I run it manually, but not when the Workbook_Open event runs

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file which when it opens the Workbook_Open event runs the code below.  Everything seems to be working correctly, except for a single line of code.  The lines of code which state wb.Close savechanges:=False are not executing what is required.

If I immediately trigger this event myself from the Visual Basic editor it runs and then this line of code works.

This does not seem to be an issue if I have the file saved on my hard drive.  It only does this when I have the file saved on OneDrive.  I am not running this from Excel online.  I am running it within the Excel application and opening the file from OneDrive.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Pull User_Name
        Range("U_Nm").Value = Application.UserName

    'Pull Serial Number from Computer
        Dim fsObj   As Object
        Dim drv     As Object
        Set fsObj = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        Set drv = fsObj.Drives("C")

        Range("SN").Value = Left(Hex(drv.SerialNumber), 4) _
             & "-" & Right(Hex(drv.SerialNumber), 4)

    Range("Current_Date").Value = Date

    'Sheets("Security").Visible = xlSheetVeryHidden
    Sheets("Security").Visible = True


    '**********CHECK CURRENT VALUES FIRST...IF PASSES THEN PASS...IF IT DOESN'T PASS THEN UPDATE...IF NO INTERNET CONNECTION REQUEST THEY CONNECT TO INTERNET TO CONNECT**********

    If Range("Full_Validation").Value <> "Valid" Then

        'you must be connected to the internet to proceed

        Sheets("Security").Range("Licensing").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        ActiveSheet.Calculate

        If Range("User_Validation").Value <> "Valid" Then

            Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

            intMessage = MsgBox("You need to register with Doug & Mark!" & vbCr _
            & vbCr _
            & "Click 'Yes' below to submit your registration information.  You will be notified when your registration is complete." & vbCr _
            & vbCr _
            & "The information below will be required to complete the registration form." & vbCr _
            & vbCr _
            & "User Name:  " & Application.UserName & vbCr _
            & "Computer:  " & Range("SN").Value & vbCr _
            & "Excel Version:  " & Application.Version & " running on " & Application.OperatingSystem, vbYesNo, "Invalid User!")

            If intMessage = vbYes Then
                objShell.Run ("https://forms.gle/xjB7yA2ehHfU6xoV6")
            Else
                'Wscript.Quit
            End If

            MsgBox "The information below is required to complete the registration form." & vbCr _
            & vbCr _
            & "User Name:  " & Application.UserName & vbCr _
            & "Computer:  " & Range("SN").Value & vbCr _
            & "Excel Version:  " & Application.Version & " running on " & Application.OperatingSystem, vbInformation, "Invalid User!"

            wb.Close savechanges:=False

        ElseIf Range("SN_Validation").Value <> "Valid" Then

           Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

           intMessage = MsgBox("You need to register with Doug & Mark!" & vbCr _
            & vbCr _
            & "Click 'Yes' below to submit your registration information.  You will be notified when your registration is complete." & vbCr _
            & vbCr _
            & "The information below will be required to complete the registration form." & vbCr _
            & vbCr _
            & "User Name:  " & Application.UserName & vbCr _
            & "Computer:  " & Range("SN").Value & vbCr _
            & "Excel Version:  " & Application.Version & " running on " & Application.OperatingSystem & "!", vbYesNo, "Invalid License!")

            If intMessage = vbYes Then
                objShell.Run ("https://forms.gle/xjB7yA2ehHfU6xoV6")
            Else
                'Wscript.Quit
            End If

            MsgBox "The information below is required to complete the registration form." & vbCr _
            & vbCr _
            & "User Name:  " & Application.UserName & vbCr _
            & "Computer:  " & Range("SN").Value & vbCr _
            & "Excel Version:  " & Application.Version & " running on " & Application.OperatingSystem & "!", vbInformation, "Invalid User!"

            wb.Close savechanges:=False

        ElseIf Range("Expiry_Validation").Value <> "Valid" Then

            Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

            intMessage = MsgBox("Your Investment Calculator subscription has Expired!" & vbCr _
                & vbCr _
                & "You will need to renew your subscription to the Investment Calculator." & vbCr _
                & vbCr _
                & "Click 'Yes' to renew your subscription now.", _
                vbYesNo, "Subscription Renewal")

            If intMessage = vbYes Then
                objShell.Run ("https://www.sltrib.com/sports/byu-cougars/")
            Else
                'Wscript.Quit
            End If

            wb.Close savechanges:=False

        End If

        'Sheets("Security").VeryHidden = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End If

    If Range("Expiry_Date").Value - 5 <= Date Then

        Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

        If Range("Expiry_Date").Value - Date = 0 Then

            intMessage = MsgBox("Your Investment Calculator subscription will expire Today!" & vbCr _
                & vbCr _
                & "You will need to renew your subscription to the Investment Calculator." & vbCr _
                & vbCr _
                & "Click 'Yes' to renew your subscription now.", _
                vbYesNo, "Subscription Renewal")

        ElseIf Range("Expiry_Date").Value - Date = 1 Then

            intMessage = MsgBox("Your Investment Calculator subscription will expire in " & Range("Expiry_Date").Value - Date & " day!" & vbCr _
                    & vbCr _
                    & "You will need to renew your subscription to the Investment Calculator." & vbCr _
                    & vbCr _
                    & "Click 'Yes' to renew your subscription now.", _
                    vbYesNo, "Subscription Renewal")

        ElseIf Range("Expiry_Date").Value - Date > 0 Then

            intMessage = MsgBox("Your Investment Calculator subscription will expire in " & Range("Expiry_Date").Value - Date & " days!" & vbCr _
                & vbCr _
                & "You will need to renew your subscription to the Investment Calculator." & vbCr _
                & vbCr _
                & "Click 'Yes' to renew your subscription now.", _
                vbYesNo, "Subscription Renewal")

        End If

        If intMessage = vbYes Then
            objShell.Run ("https://www.sltrib.com/sports/byu-cougars/")
        End If

    End If

    If Range("Full_Validation").Value = "Invalid" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    End If


    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'Range("U_Nm").ClearContents
    'Range("SN").ClearContents

End Sub
```

I would expect the same behavior that the file would close when this line of code runs.  It does work when I have it on my hard drive or it does run if I manually trigger the event.  It doesn't work though if it is on OneDrive and is run automatically with the Workbook_Open event.

Comment: Can I upload the attachment?

Comment: My first suggestion is to fully qualify all of your ranges, and remove any kinds of `ActiveSheet` etc., then see if the behavior is still the same.

Comment: Do you use `Option Explicit`? I am asking because there is no declaration of `objShell`and  `intMessage` in your posted code. Nevertheless the code is working fine and I guess the issue might be the following: All the if condtions in your code will never execute a `workbook.close`- And the last if condition `If Range("Full_Validation").Value = "Invalid" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
    End If` is not met.

Comment: When I added `Option Explicit`, and explicitly defined `objShell` and `intMessage`, code works ok for me (I had to name ranges to test it).

Comment: Can you help me understand where Option Explicit, objShell, and intMessage need to be used.  I by no means am an expert so any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.